# Dudas sobre Firma Digital en C#

Tags: c#

Muestro este código ya que con este código genero actualmente mi firma digital, lo que quiero es añadir a mi firma los `NameSpace` a `SignedInfo` para que quede como esto:

> SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte EnvioDTE_v10.xsd"

Este es mi código y por mas que lo veo no se como insertarlo... ¿quizás con `replace`?

```
public static XmlDocument FirmarDocumento(XmlDocument xmldocumentD, X509Certificate2 certificadoD, string referenciaUriD)
        {

        // Create a SignedXml object.
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmldocumentD);

        // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
        signedXml.SigningKey = certificadoD.PrivateKey;

        Signature XMLSignature = signedXml.Signature;
        // Create a reference to be signed.
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "#" + referenciaUriD;

        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);

        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        XMLSignature.SignedInfo.AddReference(reference);
        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)certificadoD.PrivateKey));

        ////
        //// Agregar información del certificado x509
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificadoD));
        XMLSignature.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        // Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
        // it to an XmlElement object.
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

        // Append the element to the XML document.
        xmldocumentD.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmldocumentD.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

        return xmldocumentD;
    }
```

Comment: Te dejo un enlace a la documentación de Microsoft. En el se explica como añadir la propiedad SignedInfo a tu XML. [Signature.SignedInfo (Propiedad) - Documentación Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signature.signedinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) Espero que te sirva, un saludo!